# underscore template is not working in backbone

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

In my `view.js` I am calling the wine-list-tpl (template), as below you can see this. But nothing is showing to the index page. Please help.

**IN index.html**

```
<script type="text/template" id="wine-list-tpl">
Hello world 
<%= name %>
</script>
.......
<div class="wine-list"></div>
```

**IN view.js**

```
var WineLists = Backbone.View.extend({

el:'.wine-list',

template : _.template($('#wine-list-tpl').html()),

render: function(){
    console.log("rendering is ok");
    this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ));
    return this;
    }
}); 

var WineList = Backbone.View.extend({
model:wines,

initialize: function(){ 
    var self=this;
    wines.fetch();
    _.each(this.model.toArray(), function(wine, i){

        $('#wine-list').append((new WineLists({ model : wine })).render().$el);

        });
    }
});

var wineListView = new WineList();
```

I have added some data in to my local storage and i just want to show those data to that particular div element.

In WineLists view i am getting all those data. means when i am writing, console.log(this.model.get('name')); I got my desired data, but i only want to show those data through template to that particular div. what should i do, please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var WineLists = Backbone.View.extend({

model: new Wine(),

template : _.template($('#myTpl').html()),

render: function(){
//console.log(this.model.get('name'));
this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
return this;
} });   

var WineList = Backbone.View.extend({
model:wines,
el:'.wineDiv',
initialize: function(){ 
var self=this;
wines.fetch();
_.each(this.model.toArray(), function(wine, i){

self.$el.append((new WineLists({ model : wine })).render().$el);

});}});

var wineListView = new WineList();


//please check ur DOM manipulation i think there is some error in ur HTML try to change call //sequence
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how your code should have been for expected results.

```
var WineLists = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.wine-list',
    render: function () {
        var _self = this;
        this.collection.each(function (model) {
            var view = new WineListItemView({
                model: model
            })
            view.render();
            view.$el.appendTo(_self.el);
        })
        return this;
    }
});



var WineListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($('#wine-list-tpl').html()),
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});

var wines = new Backbone.Collection([{
    name: 'wine1'
}, {
    name: 'wine2'
}])
var wineListView = new WineLists({
    collection: wines
});
wineListView.render()
```

Comment: sir, I have added some data in to my local storage and i just want to show those data to that particular div element.

Comment: In WineLists view i am getting all those data. means when i am writing, console.log(wine.get'name'); I got my desired data, but i only want to show those data through template to that particular div. what should i do, please suggest.